# Creating function to plot multiple distribution plots for every unique value in column

Tags: python, function, for-loop, matplotlib, seaborn

I am struggling with this function.
What I need this function to do is plot X number of seaborn displots (in a separate figure) for every unique value in a column.
In my example below I am using the iris dataset converted to a dataframe with three additional columns added: `city`,`color`,`period`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from matplotlib import rcParams
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris=load_iris()
df=pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])

df['city']=np.random.choice(['New York','Paris','London'],size=len(df))
df['period']=np.random.choice(['before','after'],size=len(df))
df['color']=np.random.choice(['red','black','blue'],size=len(df))

unique_vals = df['period'].unique()
targets = [df.loc[df['period'] == val] for val in unique_vals]
for target in targets:
    sns.distplot(target[[r'petal width (cm)']], hist=False,label='shouldbedynamic')
    sns.distplot(target[[r'sepal width (cm)']], hist=False,label='shouldbedynamic')
    plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: Snippet of the above output]

So far this code is able to plot two measures I defined split by X variable (in this case `period`).
Let's say now I want to see the exact same output (same measures and split by `period` plotted) but for **every value** in the `city` column a new plot/figure would be generated. I can do this manually of course by filtering one value at a time, but in the case that `city` has 50 unique values I would need a function to iterate through and plot 50 separate distributions instead.

In addition to this I have **two smaller questions**:

- In the existing code how can I set the `label` option to dynamically generate a legend showing what the colored lines represent?
- Similar question: is it possible to set the color lines to another color in the scope of the existing function?

EDIT: Just want to make clear what I want is to be able to plot the distributions in separate plots (not in the same).So if `city` has 50 distinct values, the same figure in the picture would be generated for each city's data: New York, Paris, London, etc.

Comment: Have a look at the FacetGrid solution proposed towards the end of this issue (the one with the image): https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/861. I can't imagine a plot with 50 distributions on top of each other has much utility though. You might want to rethink the visualisation.

Comment: Thanks, that actually seems more efficient than the current way I am splitting by the 'period' variable. But what I am looking for is for  50 separate figures to be generated for each `city` variable (not in the same figure).

Comment: then your image is very confusing. Look at the [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) main docs, that is its intended purpose. Search the page for "“Wrap” a column variable with many levels into the rows:"

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want 50 separate plots (one for each city, and split by period)? Or you want 50 distribution in the same plot (one for each city, not split by period)?

Getting dynamic labels is easy, just use `groupby` rather than `unique`

```py
for period, group in df.groupby('period'):
    sns.distplot(group[[r'petal width (cm)']], hist=False, label=f'petal: {period}')
    sns.distplot(group[[r'sepal width (cm)']], hist=False, label=f'sepal: {period}')

plt.legend()
```

You can also set the `color` parameter of `sns.distplot` to select whatever colours you want, but with 50 plots you might want to look at [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)

EDIT:

Now it's a bit more clear what you want, you could try something like this

```py
def plot_city(city_name, data):
    """ generate plot for one city """

   measures = {
        'petal width (cm)': 'tab:orange',
        'sepal width (cm)': 'tab:blue',
    }

    line_styles = {
        'before': '--',
        'after': '-',
    }

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 9))

    for measure, colour in measures.items():
        for period, group in data.groupby('period'):
            sns.distplot(
                ax=ax,
                a=group[measure], 
                hist=False, 
                label=f'petal: {period}', 
                color=colour,
                kde_kws={'linestyle':line_styles[period]}
            )

    ax.set_title(city_name, fontsize=24)
    ax.set_xlabel('width (cm)', fontsize=18)
    plt.legend(fontsize=18) 

    return fig


for city_name, data in df.groupby('city'):
    fig = plot_city(city_name, data)
    fig.savefig(f'./{city_name}.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I want 50 separate plots - one for each city, but still split by the `period` column. The groupby works perfectly, thanks. Although I already tried adding the color option, but since each measure is being split by period, I get 2 colors of the same graph, which I don't want. I'll check out colormaps.

Comment: I edited my answer. This will save 50 different plots. Alternatively you could fit them all onto one giant plot with 50 subplots using `plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=10)`

Comment: Thanks so much, this seems to give me exactly what I need.